# I have this following simple view . Then why is this ValueError is coming

Tags: python, django

This is my views.py

```
def user_profile(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    if request.method == "POST":
        fm = EditUserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if fm.is_valid():
            messages.success(request,'Profile updated')
            fm.save()
        else:
            if request.user.is_superuser == True:
                fm = EditAdminProfileForm(instance = request.user)
            else:
                fm = EditUserProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        return render(request,'enroll/profile.html',{'name':request.user,'form':fm})
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')``
```

This error is coming-

Exception Type:-    ValueError

Exception Value:-The view enroll.views.user_profile didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see this question named [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: Your function returns None in some cases, particularly with a GET. So just trace thorugh your code in that case. You have a POST case but not a GET case.

Answer (score 2):

You did not cover the case where `request.user.is_authenticated` is `True`, but the `request.method` is *not* a POST request:

```
def user_profile(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            fm = EditUserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
            if fm.is_valid():
                messages.success(request, ‘Profile updated’)
                fm.save()
            else:
                if request.user.is_superuser == True:
                    fm = EditAdminProfileForm(instance = request.user)
                else:
                    fm = EditUserProfileForm(instance=request.user)
                return render(request, 'enroll/profile.html' ,{'name':request.user, 'form' :fm})
        else:
            # ... case not covered yet (!)
            pass
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
```

You thus should implement logic that will return a `HttpResponse` for the case with the exclamation mark `(!)`.